# When i change True to False in the first code my output stays same.Why is that?

Tags: python-3.x, try-except

My code:

```
liste = ["345","sadas","324a","14","zxc"]

for i in liste:
    try:
        int(i) == True  #(make it false for example)
        print(i)
    except:
        pass



for i in liste:
    try:
         i = int(i)
        print(i)
    except:
        pass
```

output:

```
345

14
```

Here as you can see there are two different codes and the question is only write the numbers not letters.(By using try-except). But my question is when i change True to False in the first code my output stays same.Why is that?

Comment: I am going to guess here, but if `int(i)` is supposed to throw an exception if the `i` is not a number, then it will do so regardless of what you compare the outcome to, `int("sadas")` is going to throw an exception regardless of whether you compare the result (that you don't get because of the exception) with False or True.

Comment: Please check your indentation, here it is wrong. `int(i) == True` is evaluated, not tested. Didn't you mean an `if int(i) == False: ...`? Anyway, the concept of try except in this exercise is exactly to avoid using an "if".

Comment: You should probably be using `i.isdigit()` anyway. Then you can remove the try except

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
    int(i) == True  #(make it false for example)
```

first try to make an `int` of `i`, and if the operation succeeds, compares it with `True`, then discard the result of the test. IOW, the whole comparison ends up being  a no-op ((functionally speaking - the code is still executed), and could as well be replaced with just

```
`int(i)`
```

Of course since the result of the comparison is discarded, you could test against just any value that's comparable with an int (another int, a float, a bool etc), this would make absolutely no difference.

As a side note: this:

```
try:
   something()
except:
    pass
```

is pure evil - it catches absolutely everything (including a `SystemExit`) and ignore it. I understand this is just a quick test code snippet, but do yourself a favour and **never** do this in real code - always specify the exact exception(s) you expect and can handle at this point in the code, and if you want to ignore them, *at least* log them somewhere so you know what *really* happens in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> when i change True to False in the first code my output stays same

Because you're not doing anything with that result, as compared to

```
if int(i) == True:
    print(i)
```

Or simply

```
if int(i):
    print(i)
```

But, more appropriate would be

```
if i.isdigit():
    print(i)
```